# Inflating class android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to implement SwipeRefreshLayout in fragments. It is looking created  correctly, but I continue to get the errors:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: 
Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: 
Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.weather.rainy- 
2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.weather.rainy- 
2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

I really don't have any idea what is causing this.

My fragment layout for implementing the SwipeRefreshLayout:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh4Maps"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topRL4Maps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_purple"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="64dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="64dp"
        tools:context="com.weather.rainy.ui.MapsActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yourLocationLabelTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@+string/your_location"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/addressValueTextView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addressValueTextView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/yourLocationLabelTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            tools:context="com.weather.rainy.ui.MapsActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/addressValueTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/map"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/map"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@+string/..."
            android:textColor="#aaffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And, my fragment class for calling the SwipeRefreshLayout:

```
  //Code for Swipe Refresh
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh4Maps);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.Red, R.color.Orange, R.color.Blue, R.color.Green);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            Log.v(TAG, "************** MAPS - SWIPE REFRESH EVENT TRIGGERED!!!!!");
            findLocation();
        }
    });
```

I really don't have any clue, what is the wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: check your drawables and images.. must one them which is creating problem

Comment: Are you using `androidx`?

Comment: @PedroOliveira I used androidx

Comment: @SantanuSur even check it, but no problem

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Because you are using AndroidX, your XML is referencing the wrong version of `SwipeRefreshLayout`

Change in your XML from `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` to `androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira
I'm really tired of `androidx` because I can't find a mapping list to replace the old packages. Do you know where to find the mapping?

Comment: @Alston https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings

Answer (score 58):

I was stuck on the `SwipeRefreshLayout` using **AndroidX**

I was not able to get Reference of `SwipeRefreshLayout` in **AndroidX**

So I added `implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0'`
dependency in app level gradle file.

So in my case solution is,

**Add the dependency in app level *build.gradle* file**

```
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Doesn't `com.google.android.material:material` dependency include this?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky It was availabe in `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0` version but `SwipeRefreshLayout` is not available in latest version

Answer (score 18):

**This issue seems to happen when migrating to AndroidX** as there are many build artifact to be changed when Migrating to AndroidX.

## Solution 1: Do it manually

For exemple:

`android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` **changed to =>** `androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`

You must update all the build artifact listed in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

## Solution 2: Automate on Android Studio 3.2+

As suggested in this same link, you could automate this process by selecting **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** from the menu bar.

---

> *ADDITIONAL INFO - The errors I had:*
>
> **Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout**
>
> **element WebView is not allowed here**

Answer (score 11):

Gradle needs to new dependency which is AndroidX:

```
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0'
```

> If you use SwipeRefreshLayout in Java class, you can see this line:
> `import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;`

In you XML file, you should use the tags of SwipeRefreshLayout:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
```